# How to build string with Bullet format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to display string as

> ```
> . string1
> . string2
> . string3
> ```

By using Append function of Jquery how to build string with bullet format.

Comment: Do you mean in a bullet point list?

Comment: You want a `<ul>` bulleted list, or just bullet characters? Either way. it's just text. You build it like you would any OTHER text.

Comment: This is far too vague a question. Please review [ask]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<ul style="list-style-type: normal;" id="list"></ul>

<script>
    $('#list').append('<li>string1</li>');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as html lists are set up using `ul` and `li` tags, we can create a html list as follows:

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

To append to it using jQuery:

```
$(".myList").append("<li>New Item</li>");
```

See the following JSFiddle to see it in action: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3z37hw3/) - 
That code adds an item to the list after 3 seconds, so you can see it being appended.